# Orange Biolab custom widget learner input

Tags: orange

I was able to install [the demo widget](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/doc/development/source/tutorial-channels.rst) in Orange 3.9.1 and made it work with these learners

- Naive bayes
- Logistic regression

In other words I was able to connect the nodes to the newly installed "Learning curve A" widget.

This is the catch: Those two were the only I was able to connect.
For example, I can't connect the tree learner or the random forest learnear.

You can see what I mean from the picture below.
Find here [the source](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/doc/development/source/orange-demo/orangedemo/OWLearningCurveA.py) of the demo widget
In the tutorial you can see other learners are connected successfully.

Any idea why I can't connect the other learners?

[image: orange canvas]